# Count unique based on other column value Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet as follows:

[image]

How can I count the unique occurrence in column A based on the value "yes" in column B?

Expected value: 2

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A:A,B:B,"yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try if it might be easier to visualize what's happening.

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,B:B="yes))
```